# Android Canvas rendering

Tags: java, canvas, rendering, draw, surfaceview

I'm making a game and I want to partially hide the canvas of a SurfaceView like this:

From this:
[image]
To this:
[image]

Is there any way to do this with Canvas methods? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in the method that draws on the canvas:

```
            Path invertedCircle = new Path();
            int radius = (canvas.getWidth() < canvas.getHeight()) ? canvas
                    .getWidth() / 4 : canvas.getHeight() / 2;
            invertedCircle.addCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2,
                    canvas.getHeight() / 2, radius, Direction.CW);
            invertedCircle.setFillType(FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawPath(invertedCircle, p);
```

This fills everything except a circle (at the center) with black. If you have drawn your rectangles and the white background first then this should get you close.